# Delegate for UITextField not working...Return button not responding

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

I've just started with xcode and objective-c and did some very basic apps, but what i'm having problem with is very basic this. the keyboard return button not hiding the keyboard.

I've searched the internet for the solution and all they say is to connect delegate to the file's owner and add the function and it should work, i did that and nothing is working.

I have an ok button and it is working and also clicking on any free space on the screen is working, just the return button....

I am using the simulator, not testing on iphone yet. (xcode 3.2.5 64 bit with the 4.2 simulator).

This is the line of code that should connect the delegate to every textFiled.
1. i've tried already to return both `YES` and `NO`, didn't work.
2. i've tried both a specific object name for the textField and this general way, didn't work.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}
```

In the: basic view controller connection -> connections -> outlets, i have the: delegate -- File's Owner. and in the file's owner in referencing outlets there is: delegate - Round style text.....

**EDIT - i forgot to mention before, i've check and the method isn't being called!!!**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"Working!!!");
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

}

what should i do to make it happen? that is why people say to connect the delegate, but in my case it is connected and not triggering the function...i know it is kind of dumb question but for a nobie like me the solution is not obvious...

**OK, another Edit - with all my code: just can't understand what to do....**
This is: `basicViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface basicViewController : <#superclass#> <UITextFieldDelegate>

@interface basicViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
//every object that we want to interact with (like text field or lable) is call an   outlet!!!!
//here we define the outlets for our program
IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
 }

//here are the getters and setter for our outlets
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;

//method decleration for the OK button action
- (IBAction) doSomething;



//method for hiding the keyboard when clicking on empty area in the app
   //we will put an invisible button on all area and clicking on it will make keyboard disapear
   - (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway;

   @end
```

This is `basicViewController.m`:

```
 #import "basicViewController.h"

 @implementation basicViewController

 //synthesizeing the objects that we made' this will create the getter and setters automaticly
 @synthesize txtName;
 @synthesize lblMessage;

 - (IBAction) doSomething{
// makeing keyboard disapear when pressing ok button (doing that form the text field)
//when pressing the OK button, the keyboard will disapear and when clicking in the text field it will show again
[txtName resignFirstResponder];



NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",txtName.text];

//the objective-c way for setting the test in the text field
[lblMessage setText:msg];   
//the regular object oriented way
//lblMessage.text = msg;
[msg  release];
 }    

 - (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway{
[txtName resignFirstResponder];
 } 

 //when clicking the return button in the keybaord
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"Working!!!");
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
 }


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }

 - (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
 }


 - (void)dealloc {
     [super dealloc];
 }

 @end
```

Maybe now i am more clear, sorry i didn't do it before.
Any one has an idea what am i doing wrong? it should be pretty strait forward.....

**EDIT - Adding an image of all the elements, i hope that will help to help me :-)**
[image]

10x a lot for every one that is trying to help....i really like this framework, it is so great after c++ and java, python and many other...and i am working with a book, but it is for ios 3.1, maybe that is the problem.....

Comment: Are you really using text field?
Again check it ,it might be UITextView.

Comment: if the method isn't being called you should follow the steps in my answer below which should get you going.

Comment: ok, i'm trying this now, but i thought you said that it has to be be called before doing the other stuff....i'll be beck with YES or NO (objective-c style) soon....LOL

Comment: It is problem of connection bro nothing else.Ok select files owener and open inspector now select your textField IBoutlet name from view.now you see delegate in connection inspector now make this connection to file's owner. This always works so check properly.

Comment: 10x Ishu, i know it should work, i've read it in many place, to connect the delegate to the File's owner and ass the function and it should work, but it is just not working....this is the last resort place for me, when the internt fails....i've tried it again few times now, and still not working.....don't have a clue....\

Comment: p.s. I can see in the inspector -> connection that the textName textField have a delegate to Files Owner in the outlet area of the inspector and also a delegate - Files owner in the referencing outlets

Comment: I've put together a quick sample project for you. You are either missing an IBOutlet connection between your UITextField object and the controller, or you are not setting up your text field delegate properly. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Firstly you should check if `textFieldShouldReturn:` is actually being called by adding an NSLog statement or breakpoint at the beginning of the method.

Once that's out of the way, try an manually declare that your view controller conforms to `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol in your interface file:

`@interface YourClass : ... <UITextFieldDelegate>`

Also declare a property & outlet for your `UITextField`, make the appropriate connections in IB and manually declare `self` as the `UITextField` delegate with:

`self.yourUITextFieldObject.delegate = self;`

Once that's done see if your method above is now being called and make sure you return YES.

Comment: I had missed "self.yourUITextFieldObject.delegate = self;" statement. Finally got it solved! Thanks and +1.

Comment: Thanks @Rog self.yourUITextFieldObject.delegate = self; this line of code solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just write one line in the

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
}
```

before return YES;
the final version will be as given below:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the delegate of the textfields to your file owner. The textfields are sending the message, but doesn't have a delegate to respond to it.

Use the interface builder to do that.
You have to implement this method..

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Right. Just need to be sure to have set the file owner as the textfield delegate. Otherwise the textfield will send the return message but nobody will answer it. You can set the delegate using the interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

Like Rog said, don't forget to register the textfield to the delegate, you can do this manually as he said but in Storyboard you can just control drag from all of your textfields to the view controller and register the delegate (choose delegate). Only the textfields that are registered can make use of all those methods.

So this line is important:

```
self.yourUITextFieldObject.delegate = self;
```

Or even more easy these days is to just use the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: I accidentally autocompleted to `UITextViewDelegate` rather than `UITextFieldDelegate`. Knowing that i had 'added' `UITextFieldDelegate` i didn't look for quiet some time.

Answer (score 2):

textfield is in a subview? in this case, make sure textfield have as delegate the FileOwner.

Comment: Great...this is the answer I'm looking for...!

Answer (score 1):

put a log at the

```
- (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway
```

function. I think its this method everytime anything is tapped on the screen. In that case, you will need to send the touch event to the text field. Not sure how this is done but that should do it.
Else try removing the which takes care of tap(click) all over the view and try to do what you are doing.

Comment: 10x, perfect....removed binding for all screen and it is working perfect...now i guess that it just covered the keyboard or something....10x

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is that your actual view controller in the running application is not a "basicViewController" but a UIViewController that does not implement the UITextFieldDelegate-protocol.

What you've done in the interface builder by selecting your class "basicViewController" as the FilesOwner is just **declaring** the FilesOwner-object in your running application to be of type basicViewController; the actual object is **not** instantiated by this declaration and in your case it is not in the xib / nib.

Some other part of your code actually instantiates a view controller object and loads the xib / nib file. At that place, I guess your code is instantiating a UIViewController (typically by auto-generated code) and not an instance of your basicViewController; you simply have to change the class there.

Furthermore, this error often happens when using a UINavigationController or UITabBarController in the Interface Builder that is (should be) configured to instantiate and load other custom views. If you use such a higher-level controller, double-check that it is actually configured to use your basicViewController, not UIViewController when loading your view from the xib / nib.

Hope, that solves the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can always dismiss the keyboard when you don’t even know which view the text field is in by using:

**Objective-C:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) 
                                           to:nil 
                                         from:nil 
                                     forEvent:nil];
```

**Swift:**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", 
                                           to:nil, 
                                         from:nil, 
                                     forEvent:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this..

```
@interface ClassName : SuperClass < UITextFieldDelegate >
```

Comment: This is only if you want to override a delegate method..... there is no reason doing this otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this...

```
textfield.delegate=self;
```

and use the `UITextFieldDelegate` in   .h class

Comment: I had a UICollectionViewController which programmatically generated UITextFields and couldn't figure out why the done key wasn't firing.  This did the trick.